# Menu links are overlapping in mobile view

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, flexbox, css-transitions

[image]

[image]

This are the two images, after dopping down mwnus original menu which is behind this overlaps with each other.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably an `absolute: position;` on the submenu. If you want it to appear above the main menu items, add a `z-index: 10;` if you want it to appear within the main menu & push the other navigation items down, give the submenu a `position: relative;`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use these properties in the parent div (Products) of those sub parts

display: flex;
flex-direction: column; //arranges them in column
justify-content: space-between; //provides equal spaces

This is also more responsive as display : flex; arranges elements according to the space available